# Custom Code Of Plugin is not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, syntax-error

This is my plugins code and it not executing properly. When i activate my plugin in wordpress then this error will generated Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\AdsKanikase\AdsKanikase.php on line 32 . Please help me out to activaye my plugin thanks. Please help me out.

```
  <?php 
/* 
Plugin Name: AdsKanikase 
Description: Plugin para forzar click en la publicidad antes de mostrar un enlace 
Version: 1.0 
Author: kanikase 
Author URI: http://kanikase.com 
*/ 
?>

<?php
// obtenemos las configuraciones 
$adskanikase_configs = get_option('adskanikase_configs'); 

// funcion para encriptar los datos que estan en base64 
function encrypt_content($string, $key){ 
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key)))); 
} 

// la funcion que hara que se cambie el shortcode por la publicidad en los posts 
function adskanikase_shortcode($atts, $content) { 
    // agregamos la variable de las configuraciones 
    global $adskanikase_configs; 
    // datos que vamos a poner en el div como data-id 
    $arr = array( 
        'url'   => $content, 
        'image' => $atts['image'], 
        'text' => $atts['text'], 
    ); 
    // los datos en json, encriptados 
    $data = str_replace('+', '-', encrypt_content(json_encode($arr), $adskanikase_configs['key']));
function adskanikase_shortcode($atts, $content) { 
    // agregamos la variable de las configuraciones 
    global $adskanikase_configs; 
    // datos que vamos a poner en el div como data-id 
    $arr = array( 
        'url'   => $content, 
        'image' => $atts['image'], 
        'text' => $atts['text'], 
    ); 
    // los datos en json, encriptados 
    $data = str_replace('+', '-', encrypt_content(json_encode($arr), $adskanikase_configs['key'])); 
    return <<<HTML 
<div id="adsClick" data-id="{$data}"> 
    <span class="texto">{$adskanikase_configs['texto']}</span> 
    <div id="pubpub"> 
        {$adskanikase_configs['codigo']} 
    </div> 
</div> 
HTML; 
} 
// agregamos el shortcode 
add_shortcode($adskanikase_configs['shortcode'], 'adskanikase_shortcode');
<?php 
// agregar javascript 
function add_js_adskanikase() { 
    $datos = array('ajaxurl' => plugins_url('get_link.php', __FILE__)); 
    wp_enqueue_script('AdsKanikase', plugins_url('scripts.js', __FILE__)); 
    wp_localize_script('AdsKanikase', 'AdsKanikase', $datos); 
} 
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_js_adskanikase');
```

Comment: escape all `"` like `\"` from `return <<<HTML` to `HTML`, after that replace both `<<<HTML,HTML` with an single `"` like `return " \" $a \" ";`

Comment: or get an dev-tool like PHPStrom/Netbeans that helps you to create `<<<HTML HTML;` correct.